# Why doesn't my code to get pixel data from an image work?

Tags: javascript, getimagedata

I made this code to cycle through every pixel in an image and output its RGBA value to the console. Why doesn't it work as intended? I seem to be getting all [0,0,0,0]s for PixelData. I tried several pieces of code from stackoverflow.com but they didn't help. My ultimate goal is to compare these colors to a list of other colors and pick the closest one for each pixel, but I should be able to do that alone once I get this part answered.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<img id="myImage" src="img.png" width="64px" height="64px"></img>
<script>
var img = document.getElementById('myImage');
var mycanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
mycanvas.width = img.width;
mycanvas.height = img.height;
var context = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
for(var x=1;x<=16;x++){
for(var y=1;y<=16;y++){
var pixelData = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
console.log("x="+x.toString()+" y="+y.toString()+" pD="+pixelData.toString()+" ");
}}
</script></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might not be giving your image enough time to load and render. Try using `img.onload` like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('myImage');

img.onload = function() {
  var mycanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  mycanvas.width = img.width;
  mycanvas.height = img.height;
  var context = mycanvas.getContext('2d');
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  for(var x=1;x<=16;x++){
    for(var y=1;y<=16;y++){
      var pixelData = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
      console.log("x="+x.toString()+" y="+y.toString()+" pD="+pixelData.toString()+" ");
    }
  }
}
```

Oh, and one more thing... Move your `<img...>` tag out of the `head` section of your HTML and into the `body`. I'm not sure an image will even load if it's in the `head` section. If you do this either your script will have to follow the image, or you'll have to wrap your script in a function that's called when your document finishes loading, e.g. `<body onload="init()">`.

Update:

I found this post about putting an `img` in your `head` section. It sounds like you're likely to get away with it, but you shouldn't count on it: [Will an html image tag execute in the head tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469587/will-an-html-image-tag-execute-in-the-head-tag)

Comment: It worked but now I get the error that the console is tainted. Once again I tried a lot of options that I found on this website and none of them worked.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that the canvas, not the console, is tainted. Are you using images from a different server than the server that hosts your web page? (Causing a CORS issue?)

Comment: You're right, it's the canvas. The thing is that it's not a web page, it's a file. The picture is in the same directory as the file, as you can see from the code.

Comment: Never mind, I put this on GitHub and it worked. Apparently CORS doesn't support file://, only http:// and https://. That's really annoying.